# I have an error "E/RecyclerView : No adapter attached: skipping layout"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

My application closes when I access the activity where my RecyclerView is, it tells me that the problem is in my adapter but being new in this the truth is that I do not know what the solution could be. I already looked for other answers with the same problem, but I still do not make it work

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterCategoria extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterCategoria.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Categoria> mData;
    private RequestOptions option;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterCategoria(Context mContext, List<Categoria> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;

        //Request option for Glide

        option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria_row_item, parent, false);
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);


        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_id.setText(mData.get(position).getId_categoria());
        holder.tv_nombre.setText(mData.get(position).getNombre());

        //Load image from Internet

        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getImagen_url()).apply(option).into(holder.iv_imagen);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tv_id;
        TextView tv_nombre;
        ImageView iv_imagen;
        LinearLayout view_container;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);


            view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            tv_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoria_id);
            tv_nombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoria_nombre);
            iv_imagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoria_imagen);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry! Actually I thought that I was in
 that page xd

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your problem because of language. But you title is `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` . So I think you missed to declare your Adapter in your `yourRecyclerViewActivity` class.
For basic you have to add

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,yourList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter );
```

to your `recyclerViewActivity` Class.

Answer (score 0):

@vimukthi is correct and you're probably missing this code `recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);` on the class that does the binding and call for the recyclerView.